# CentOS No Login Prompt After rc.local Executes

Tags: linux, centos, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, boot

This is a CentOS 6.4 server with no GUI. After rc.local executes in the boot sequence, I am not presented with a console style login prompt. I can type characters on the screen but there is no login prompt nor shell.

I checked `/etc/init/tty.conf` and `/etc/init/start-ttys.conf`. Everything looks normal. I am able to access the server via the recovery console and see no errors in the log files.

Please note: I converted an Amazon EC2 Machine to a RAW file, converted it to VMDK, and it is booting in VMware Fusion.

Comment: What is your default run-level? Look in `/etc/inittab`. Check also for configured TTYs in `/etc/sysconfig/init`.

Comment: default run level was 3.  i just tried it with one and i get a prmopt.

Comment: ACTIVE_CONSOLES=

instead of 

ACTIVE_CONSOLES=/dev/tty[1-6]

I'm going to try to modify that, switch it back to init3, and see if that fixes it, thanks

Comment: that didn't fix it

Comment: i lied, it just took a while to boot but it boots and i see the login, you were dead on with /etc/sysconfig/init !

Comment: @Aaron submit an answer and i'll mark it ask correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default TTY's are configured in `/etc/sysconfig/init`. Please make sure the `ACTIVE_CONSOLES=` line is configured with the default value `/dev/tty[1-6]`.

```
# What ttys should gettys be started on?
ACTIVE_CONSOLES=/dev/tty[1-6]
```